# How to get access token for azure AD Auth

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD and have to call an API to get access token to start a pipeline.

I am using OAuth2 for authorization but don't know the right way to do that.

I tried it using Postman and was able to get reponse successfully.

but when I tried the same using Angular n Node.

In Angular I got CORS error and
In Node I got a status code of 401 in message

I have endpoint URL which i'm using to get token from Azure AD which i have test on Postman something like this.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{SomeID}/oauth2/token

request headers:

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

request body:

> grant_type: client_credentials

> client_id: {Client_ID}

> client_secret: {Secret}

> resource: https://management.azure.com

For node i used third-party package name
[AXIOS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

I feel it is not right to pass the request from Angular itself so send the request from backend only make sense.

Please Help me I am stuck from 2 weeks reading documentation but not getting anywhere.

A code would be of great help.

Comment: check it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#scenarios-and-supported-authentication-flows

Comment: You can use sdk `@azure/msal-angular` to implement Azure AD auth. After doing that, you can avoid the CORS issue. For more details about how to implement, please refer to the sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/

Comment: @JimXu the example is for login popup i want to do more of a silent authentication

Comment: According to the situation, I  think you can make a backend server to request access token and call other api. If you use nodejs to create  backend server, you can refer to the sampe to get token :https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node#server-to-server-via-client-credentials

Answer (score 1):

For your Angular app you should use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) and use a security library to do the heavy lifting

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

I have an Azure AD code sample with an SPA and API that you can use to get connected:

- [Step by Step Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/30/azure-active-directory-setup/)
- [GitHub Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure)

Hopefully the blog post at least gives you some ideas of what a solution looks like technically, and you can then adapt it as you see fit.